# How having insensitive-case the Bash history completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Is there a setting to enable case-insensitive history completion for Bash?

I tried tab-completing `cd s` with `cd Socket/in` in my history but it didn't complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `~/.bashrc`-file:

`bind -s 'set completion-ignore-case on'`

More information can be found in [How to make cd arguments case INsensitive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60162/how-to-make-cd-arguments-case-insensitive).